# Trigger jquery ui dialog with link

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, hyperlink, jquery-ui-dialog

I'm trying to trigger a jQuery UI dialog with a link. Here's the link:

```
<a href="#" id="mydialog">Open the dialog</a>
```

and here's the javascript earlier on the page:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var $mydialog = $('<div></div>')
        .html('dialog body')
        .dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            title: 'dialog title'
        });
    $('#mydialog').click(function() {
        $mydialog.dialog('open');
    });
});
```

This javascript has worked before for me when using a button with the appropriate ID assigned, but it isn't working with the link. Also, I can't figure out how the stop the link redirecting to the address specified by href (putting return false in the click handler doesn't work).

Thanks guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're code isn't working on `a` tags because they're doing their default behavior.  Basically, the page is moving on before the dialog opens.  Make it stop with `event.preventDefault()`.  Notice the `function` has `event` passed in as well.

```
$('#mydialog').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $mydialog.dialog('open');
});
```

Comment: Thanks! This works fine now except when the html for the link is echoed into the page via AJAX (which is sadly what I want to do). I don't suppose you know why that is do you?